# How to configure Bochs to have 2048 MB of RAM

Tags: memory, crash, bochs

I'm running Bochs on an x64 Windows PC.

Whenever I try to set it to have >1024 MB RAM and start it, it just says "Bochs has stopped working" and crashes. I tried everything. Installing an X64 version of Bochs etc. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you even have 2048GB in the system?

Comment: 2 TB of RAM? or 2 GB of RAM?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes I do. It's a typo, it's actually meant to say 2048 MB